# Context over onCreate

Tags: java, android

I get :

```
android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

Android Studio is pointing to

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "as", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

This toast is over `onCreate` method and below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

I think it is a problem with context, but i cant debug where is null, app crash instant before breakpoint on this toast.
I tried use `this` instead `MainActivity.this` or `getAppicationContext()`
and i get this same result :/

Comment: show your oncreate ?

Comment: Can you, please, add your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This toast is over onCreate method and below

I assume you have `Toast`s as class fields that try to use the `Activity` as a `Context`. It's too early - fields are initialized when the activity instance is created. The activity is ready to use as a `Context` only in `onCreate()` or later in its lifecycle. Therefore move your `Toast` init to `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

we can't initialize Toast in Class

write in `onCreate` method

```
class MyActivity {

    oncreate{
          Toast.makeToast();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your pseudocode is possibly confusing. Please write out the full class and method declarations.